# Black screen when trying to install kubuntu macbook (2008 or 2009)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, macbook, multi-boot

So I have a MacBook, which I believe is the 2008 model, that I am trying to dual-boot kubuntu on.  Everything works fine up until the GUI is initiated (at least I think it is when the GUI is initiated), at which point I am stuck with a black screen.

What happens when I try to boot from the CD:

1). It boots from the cd

2). Kubuntu splash screen shows

3). Black screen (Can' really be considered as working but..)

4). Cd drive stops making the noise it makes

5). After five minutes or so the fan turns on